# What does it mean if my computer beeps rapidly and doesn't stop when I turn it on?

Tags: windows-7, maintenance, dell-optiplex

There is serious power failure that occurs repeatedly these days in my location, and this caused my PC to shut down suddenly as the electricity goes away(I use Desktop computer.) But when there was electricity, there was no problem, until today ,when it started making repeated rapid(really fast like 20 or 30 times per second) beeping noise( like just before detenaters explode in the movies) and never turning on. I have no lights on my keyboard, and the case has a backlight which has stayed on during the beeping. What is the problem and How can I fix it ?

I use Dell Optiplex 780 and windows 7.
*I really need help as soon as possible*.

Comment: What pattern is the beeping, and what's the frequency? Are any of the keyboard lights flashing? If so, what's the pattern? What about the lights on the computer's case?

Comment: Also, consider investing in a UPS. And please say you've got a backup; it looks like part of your hard drive is toast.

Comment: Your BIOS manual may have a table that tells what each beep code means. Maybe this? https://www.dell.com/support/article/au/en/aubsd1/sln143065/dell-optiplex-and-vostro-beep-codes-and-error-messages?lang=en

Comment: Things don't look good. You may be able to fix it. Remove the BIOS battery and any extra cards you may have installed. Remove all USB devices apart from the keyboard and screen, Unplug the power lead and leave the computer for 30 mins. Plug back in to power then attempt a switch on after putting the bios battery back in.